# how to sort this in both ascending and descending order in python?

Tags: python, sorting

The program should be able to sort the experiments
data in ascending and descending order.

```
list=['0.564', '0.787', '1.012', '1.055', '0.656', '0.665', '0.789', '2.110', '2.121', '3.325', '0.025', '3.250', '1.785', '1.998', '1.552', '2.021', '0.998', '1.001', '1.121', '0.564', '0.784', '2.001', '5.454', '5.234', '13.746', '4.785', '3.001', '3.458', '2.987', '3.658', '3.212', '4.165', '4.112', '4.000', '3.589', '3.221', '3.154', '2.118', '2.546', '2.658', '2.131', '1.989', '1.548', '2.112', '1.987', '1.555', '1.197', '1.958', '0.885', '0.847']
```

i have tried

```
sorted(list4,key=lambda )
print list4
```

but

```
File "text.py", line 41
    sorted(list4,key=lambda )
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(a4-2-225.v276.city.ac.uk)185%
```

Comment: lambda declares an anonymous function, it can't be used on it's own in this manner. You have to follow it up with something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sorted` function with the `key=float` argument to convert the strings to `float` for sorting. Then you can use the `reverse` argument to sort in either ascending or descending order.

```
>>> sorted(L, key=float)  # Ascending
['0.025', '0.564', '0.564', '0.656', '0.665', '0.784', '0.787', '0.789', '0.847', '0.885', '0.998', '1.001', '1.012', '1.055', '1.121', '1.197', '1.548', '1.552', '1.555', '1.785', '1.958', '1.987', '1.989', '1.998', '2.001', '2.021', '2.110', '2.112', '2.118', '2.121', '2.131', '2.546', '2.658', '2.987', '3.001', '3.154', '3.212', '3.221', '3.250', '3.325', '3.458', '3.589', '3.658', '4.000', '4.112', '4.165', '4.785', '5.234', '5.454', '13.746']

>>> sorted(L, key=float, reverse=True) # Descending
['13.746', '5.454', '5.234', '4.785', '4.165', '4.112', '4.000', '3.658', '3.589', '3.458', '3.325', '3.250', '3.221', '3.212', '3.154', '3.001', '2.987', '2.658', '2.546', '2.131', '2.121', '2.118', '2.112', '2.110', '2.021', '2.001', '1.998', '1.989', '1.987', '1.958', '1.785', '1.555', '1.552', '1.548', '1.197', '1.121', '1.055', '1.012', '1.001', '0.998', '0.885', '0.847', '0.789', '0.787', '0.784', '0.665', '0.656', '0.564', '0.564', '0.025']
```

Comment: thanks a lot but it still doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to cover in-place sort vs. producing a new list too. The OP seems to expect `sorted()` to do an in-place sort.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text.py", line 41, in <module>
    sorted(list4, key=float)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
(a4-2-225.v276.city.ac.uk)186%

Comment: @ZhuHigari Your list that you posted in your example has no such element. Please post your **actual** list.

Comment: @ZhuHigari: Ah, but that's because you have **non-float values** in your list. You didn't tell us everything about your data.

Comment: with open('results.txt') as f:                                                                          list4=[]
    list4.append(f.readline().split())and that list was in the results.txt